# Stack Exchange site stats - NaN%?

Tags: support, status-completed, stackexchange.com, site-stats

[image]

Stack Exchange site stats - **NaN%**?

May be the site itself shouldn't be there, since it's got merged?

Comment: IEEE-854 has been around for 24 years already, time to get used to it. Sure beats arguing whether is should say 0, 100 or 42%.

Comment: Ah, NaN. My absolute favorite (not a) number, wonderful for confounding noobs to practical floating point arithmetic who expect it all to behave algebraically. It also has the bonus of using different representations on different platforms, even after accounting for endianness (praise be to HP for pissing in that particular pool). NaN… is there nothing you can't do? (Well, except be a number of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guitars no longer appears in the Site Directory, so this is fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

That particular proposal was merged with music, as I thought it indicated somewhere. It just hasn't been removed from the stats for Area51 yet.

In the case of NaN% ... that's cos the calculation is trying to divide by zero, hence, not a number