# The statistics for Stack Overflow incorrect on Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, site-stats

There appears to be an "overflow" in the statistics for Stack Overflow on [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday):

[image]

Comment: Heh, apparently [not the first time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93228/stack-exchange-site-stats-nan) some like that's happened. Might just be a transient error that will self-correct when the stats refresh, but I'm not sure.

Comment: [so] was sold to ExpertsExchange. You'll now have to pay $9.95/mo to see the stats.

Comment: @yoda: I'm tempted to flag that comment as "offensive".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed now, thanks. (Stackexchange.com gets its site stats from [APIv2](http://api.stackexchange.com/), and the [query](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=!%29ujpi%29%29KNxE&site=stackoverflow) was timing out.)